# Retrieve records from a table which is linked to three tables MySQl

Tags: mysql

I have four SQL tables like module,lesson, unit and user

The relation between these four is module has lessson and lesson has units.

1)module -> lesson -> unit.

2)module is assigned to user table -> module_user.

I need to retrieve all modules based on user-id and unit-id how can i do that?

Table-module:

```
-module_id
@onetomany
-module_lesson
@manytomany
-module_user
```

Table-lesson:

```
lesson_id
```

Table-unit:

```
unit_id
```

Table-lesson_unit:

```
lesson_id
unit_id
```

Table-module_lesson:

```
lesson_id
module_id
```

Table-module_user:

```
module_id
user-id
```

Please give me some idea

Thanks in advance